# Canopy editor: error no module named pyspark

Tags: canopy

From canopy editor I tried import pyspark and it gives me error no module named pyspark in C:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmparhn5_.py

I tried pip install pyspark and the error is invalid syntax

then I tried import findspark and error is no module named findspark.

How resolve it?

Comment: "I tried pip install pyspark and the error is invalid syntax" Pip is a Windows application, not a Python command. So you need to run it from a Canopy Command Prompt (see the Canopy Tools menu). (That doesn't mean it will succeed -- I haven't tested that -- but at least that will get you past the syntax error)